# Sorry I didn't turn up, I clean forgot. What's the sense of "clean' and its usage hygiene?

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice, pragmatics

> 1. Sorry I didn't turn up -I **clean** forgot.
> 2. The explosion blew the cooker **clean** through the wall.

- What kind of usage is this- AmE or BrE ?

The meaning of clean usually refers to removing something unwanted: you clean your hands by washing them.

> I understand that phrasal verbs convey a different meaning
>   in contrast to the root words. So to my jarring mind, clean up appears
>   OK, but **I clean forgot** sounds wierd.

Comment: Clean:  Informal Entirely; wholly: clean forgot the appointment.http://www.thefreedictionary.com/CLean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is an informal usage:
>
> 1.Sorry I didn't turn up -I clean forgot.
>
> The adverb **clean** means **'completely'** before forget (though a tad
>   informal)...
>
> 2.The explosion blew the cooker clean through the wall. .....and some expressions of movement.

A similar usage can be of the adverb ***dead***. It is used in certain expressions to mean 'exactly',
**'completely'** or 'very'. 
Examples: dead ahead, dead certain, dead drunk.

Comment: thank you for giving another example..Other answers and comments certainly make it an "informal usage".Hope I can edit?

Answer (score 5):

*Clean* has an adverbial meaning. From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clean):

> **clean** *adv*:  all the way, completely. Example: The bullet went clean through his arm.

So, *I clean forgot* means *I completely forgot*.

Comment: These usages are as an _intensifier_. In _I clean forgot_, the usage is adverbial, but in _The bullet went clean through his arm_, the usage is as a prepositional-phrase modifier.